# Initialize dictionary from array with Swift 3

Tags: swift

Is there a more simple/efficient way to initialize a dictionary from an array in Swift 3?

```
for object in array {
    dict[object.id] = object
}
```

Nothing wrong with the above but I was wondering if you could use map/reduce/etc to do this with slightly less code.

Comment: Not in Swift 3, but https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0165-dict.md is currently been reviewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.forEach({ object in
    dict[object.id] = object
})
```

or shorter:

```
array.forEach({ dict[$0.id] = $0 })
```